# Which episode shows Naruto competing in a race to a shrine on the top of a hill?

Tags: naruto

I only remember that Naruto was competing in some kind of competition (it's not an eating contest). From the start line, they have to get to a shrine, where some kind of prize has been placed, on the very top of a hill.

I *think* it was from *Naruto*.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. I removed the last statement regarding "*any other similar anime episodes similar to this*" because that makes the question broader, unless you're asking "Which episodes show Naruto having a competition?" in the first place. Regarding the "links", take note that we don't support piracy, thus we will only provide legal links, not illegal/questionable one.

Comment: @AkiTanaka I was looking for other similar episodes, as in episodes of a race to the top of a hill for whatever reason. 
I was trying to pitch an idea at work, which is more or less inspired by this idea. Hence, my mention of other anime. The reason I specified Naruto is because as far as I remember, I saw this in Naruto.

Comment: From your original post, you described a scene from *Naruto*, and I read it that you want to know which episode *that particular scene* from, *which is perfectly acceptable*. However, the next statement "please list similar episodes like this" reads as a different "question" (request, basically), and that should be posted as a new question, or [edit] and change this whole question to that instead.

Comment: @AkiTanaka So can I rephrase the question to ask if there are any anime episodes showing the characters racing to a shrine at the top of a hill or do I have to post that as another question in forums?

Comment: considering someone has posted an answer, it's better to post a new question instead. However, please limit it to a single anime series only (e.g *Naruto*), because when you're asking for multiple anime, then it becomes anime recommendation which off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to Idate's Arc in Land of Tea Escort Mission from Episode 102-106.

As per Wikia: Source: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Land_of_Tea_Escort_Mission

> The Land of Tea Escort Mission spans from episodes 102 to 106 of the Naruto anime. Naruto, Sasuke, and Sakura go to the Land of Tea to help Idate Morino win a race. This arc is preceded by the Search for Tsunade and is followed by the Sasuke Recovery Mission.

This arc is Anime only (i.e. Filler). While filler arcs are usually not upto par with the main storyline, this was a watchable arc as it showcased the Naruto/Sasuke dynamic really well while setting up the next and best arc of the series.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the episode you are referring to is episode 240 of Naruto Shippuden: Kiba's Determination.

In the episode you see a flashback where Naruto and his friends as kids competing to reach a tree in the village where they would race to for candy.

You can find a summary of the episode on the [naruto wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kiba%27s_Determination)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Naruto, you are probably talking about the Filler episodes 103-106.